# PY files accessible outside of module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been writing a Discord bot, which has several constants that other modules use. The `config.py` file is in the application's root folder with the `bot.py` file. I have `cog` and `cl` folders that can access it. Everywhere I've read says this shouldn't be possible, but it works and has for over a year now. I'm hoping that someone can explain why, because when I started a new project using the exact same configuration, it doesn't work. I've provided some examples below:

`Python 3.11.1`

`root/config.py`

```py
GIFT_HOURS = 1               # default is 1
# default is {"1": 40, "2": 160, "3": 360, "4": 640, "5": 1000, "6": 1440}
GIFT_PRICES = {"1": 40, "2": 160, "3": 360, "4": 640, "5": 1000, "6": 1440}
# default is {"1": 2, "2": 4, "3": 6, "4": 8, "5": 10, "6": 12}
GIFT_EXPS = {"1": 2, "2": 4, "3": 6, "4": 8, "5": 10, "6": 12}
```

`root/cl/__init__.py`

```py
from .gift_manager import GiftManager
```

`root/cl/class_gift_manager.py`

```py
from config import GIFT_HOURS, GIFT_PRICES, GIFT_EXPS

class GiftManager:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.gift_hours = GIFT_HOURS
        self.gift_prices = GIFT_PRICES
        self.gift_exps = GIFT_EXPS
    enter code here

# This works and shouldn't?
```

According to what I've read, a module should not be able to access a file in the parent directory (root). Somehow mine can and it confuses me. I want to do this correctly, but the information is conflicting.

Comment: maybe you have `/full/path/to/root` in `sys.path` - and this way Python know where to search `config.py`

Comment: I guess this works because the active directory is the `root` directory because `bot.py` was ran correctly? So all relative imports are considered from that directory? Am I correct?

Comment: simply run from different folder to check it.

Comment: @furas, I didn't do any sys.path work. I figured out why my second project didn't work, it was a typo. Importing gets confusing with Python no matter how much I read about it.

Comment: @furas, yep. If I run directly from GiftManager I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`. So that must be it. Hmm.

Comment: I'm wondering if it would be a better practice to put all constants in a `config` file in the `cl` folder. That way it would run from the bot.py AND if I were to run the specific class to do testing.

Comment: if you plan to use the same constants in many files then you could put them in separated file and import to all files - rule `DRY` (`Don't Repeat Yourself`). But frankly you can always import `config.py` to all files - your constants doesn't look like constants.